# I need to bind the first name to the alt text of each LI item

Tags: vue.js

I need to bind the first name to the alt text of each LI item. Don't understand what's the problem. Can someone please help me? Thank you!

html:

`<div id = name> <label for = "firstName">First Name:</label> <input type = "text" id = "firstName" v-model = "firstName"> <br><ol><li v-for = "food in foods" :key = "food.id" :alt = "firstName">{{food.text}}</li></ol></div>`

vue.js:

```
var name = new Vue({el: "#name",data:{firstName: "lee",foods: [{id:0, text:"pizza"}, {id:1, text:"ice cream"}, {id:2, text:"sushi"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition like this on LI to show firstname as alternate text when food.text is not available.

```
<div id = name> 
    <label for = "firstName">First Name:</label> 
    <input type = "text" id = "firstName" v-model = "firstName"> <br>
    <ol>
        <li v-for = "food in foods" :key = "food.id" >{{food && food.text ? food.text : firstName}}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: so I don't need to use :alt = "firstName" inside <li> ?

Comment: but it still doesn't work with this condition

Comment: No need to use alt now.
It will show firstname only when you have food.text is undefined or null.

Answer (score 0):

`alt` is usually used as alternative text for images. If you want to show a tooltip for each `<li>` use `title` instead:

```
    <div id="name">
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input type = "text" id = "firstName" v-model = "firstName"><br>
      <ol>
        <li v-for = "food in foods" :key = "food.id" :title = "firstName">
          {{food.text}}
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reasons it just doesn't work. The first name doesn't show up in the <li> element in the page

Comment: @lee - what exactly do you mean by "work"? what are you really expecting? I am pretty sure it 'works' (shows a tooltip for the <li> tags with the current firstName) using the 'title' attribute.